# JSON schema: Specify in error message the required minimum/maximum length

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm using the jsonschema python package for python.
I have the following schema:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 5
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

In addition, I have the following JSON file to validate:

```json
{
    name: "Josh"
}
```

When I validate my JSON file against the schema above I get the error:
`'Josh' is too short`

Is there a way to also specify the expected minimum length?
Something like: `The string 'Josh' is less than the minimum length of 5`

I tried:

- Updating jsonschema package to the last version - 4.17.3.
- Use draft-07 instead of draft-04.

None of those actions changed the original error message.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```py
schema = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 5,
      "errorMessage": "The string '{0}' is less than the minimum length of {1}"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": False
}
```

`jsonschema.validate()` function will raise a `jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError` exception with the default error message `'Josh' is too short`. However, we catch this exception and replace its error message with the custom message `The string 'Josh' is less than the minimum length of 5` before re-raising it.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the proccess of catching and replacing the error message with the message in "errorMessage", is not supported by jsonschema's package and I need to implement this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of attributes available on `ValidationError`s which tell you various things about the specific error that occurred.

In this case, that's `ValidationError.validator_value`. The full list is [here](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors/).

You can catch your exception and pull whatever values you'd like off, and show whatever message is appropriate.

(The precise error message shown is indeed [not guaranteed to look any particular way](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/#how-do-jsonschema-version-numbers-work), it's designed to be as helpful to *developers* as possible, whilst balancing not being too noisy).